# How do I convert this code block into a Javascript loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

This function operates perfectly, onclick it subtracts a price amount from 7 ‘cosT’ divs and 1 ‘cosT1’ div, as if removing an item from a shopping cart.

```
function changePrice0000() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var x = document.querySelectorAll(".cosT, .cosT1");
            x[0].innerHTML = parseFloat(Number(x[0].innerHTML) - Number(x[7].innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
            x[1].innerHTML = parseFloat(Number(x[1].innerHTML) - Number(x[7].innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
            x[2].innerHTML = parseFloat(Number(x[2].innerHTML) - Number(x[7].innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
            x[3].innerHTML = parseFloat(Number(x[3].innerHTML) - Number(x[7].innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
            x[4].innerHTML = parseFloat(Number(x[4].innerHTML) - Number(x[7].innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
            x[5].innerHTML = parseFloat(Number(x[5].innerHTML) - Number(x[7].innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
            x[6].innerHTML = parseFloat(Number(x[6].innerHTML) - Number(x[7].innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
            x[7].innerHTML = parseFloat(Number(x[7].innerHTML) - Number(x[7].innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "text/p0000.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

I’ve tried a few variations of the following, nooby attempts at looping and getting it to work but without even remote success…

```
function changePrice0000() {
    for(i=0; i<7; i++) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        var x = document.querySelectorAll(".cosT, .cosT1");

        x[n].innerHTML = parseFloat(Number(x[n].innerHTML) - Number(x[7].innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
        x[0].innerHTML = parseFloat(Number(x[0].innerHTML) - Number(x[7].innerHTML)).toFixed(2);}};

        xhttp.open("GET", "text/p0000.txt", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
}
```

…way beyond my capabilities , one for the experts I think, explicit assistance or just a point in the right direction would be most gratefully appreciated.

Comment: The for loop needs to go inside the xhttp.onreadystatechange lambda. Essentially just around the `x[n]` line (although you were using i not n as a the loop variable?)

Comment: Proper indentation makes it soooooo much easier to see what's going on. I'd suggest trying to make a habit out of that.

Comment: Ok thanks @Rup, giving it a try…

Answer (score 1):

You were close, you only need the `for` loop around the part of the code you want to repeat. You also used an undefined variable `n` instead of the `i` in the loop, as @Rup mentioned in the comments:

```
function changePrice0000() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            var x = document.querySelectorAll(".cosT, .cosT1");

            for(i = 0; i<7; i++) {
                x[i].innerHTML = parseFloat(Number(x[i].innerHTML) - Number(x[7].innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
            }

            xhttp.open("GET", "text/p0000.txt", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a small snippet with a simple loop solution:

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".cost");

x.forEach(function(el) {
  el.innerHTML = parseFloat(Number(el.innerHTML) - Number(x[7].innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
  });
```

```html
<div class="cost">1</div>
<div class="cost">2</div>
<div class="cost">3</div>
<div class="cost">4</div>
<div class="cost">5</div>
<div class="cost">6</div>
<div class="cost">7</div>
<div class="cost">8</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function changePrice0000() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var x = document.querySelectorAll(".cosT, .cosT1");
      // loop over n starts here
      for (n = 0; n < 7; n++) {
        x[n].innerHTML = parseFloat(
          Number(x[n].innerHTML) - Number(x[7].innerHTML)
        ).toFixed(2);
      }
      // loop ends here
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "text/p0000.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();
  };
}
```

maybe this is what you mean? `N` is the var, so `I` from your example will not work, and you gotta makes sure your loop is inside of where you want to handle it...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so huge thank you to the blisteringly fast expert responses, bit of jigging about–here is what is working perfectly (don’t ask me how :), endeavoured to indent a bit:

```
function changePrice0000() {var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".cosT, .cosT1");

        // loop begins
        for(n=0; n<7; n++) { 

        x[n].innerHTML = parseFloat(Number(x[n].innerHTML) - Number(x[7].innerHTML)).toFixed(2)};
        // loop ends

        x[n].innerHTML = parseFloat(Number(x[n].innerHTML) - Number(x[7].innerHTML)).toFixed(2);}};

xhttp.open("GET", "text/p0000.txt", true);
xhttp.send();}
```

Thanks again guys !!!

Answer (score -1):

You just have to put [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) to the code which you want to repeat.

```
var n=7
    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            x[i].innerHTML = parseFloat(Number(x[i].innerHTML)-(Number(x[n].innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
        }
```